# How to retrieve SAS overwritten sashelp dataset?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

by mistake i overwrote the sashelp.class dataset instead of creating a new one setting the data from sashelp.class.

I need the initial stage so that i might work with exam's questions.

Is there any way to make the dataset return to its initial stage? By downloading or changing the file on my PC?

Thanks!

Comment: By default SASHELP is usually locked down. I wouldn't recommend changing this in the future if you did for some reason.

Comment: You could try this location: `https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Need-data-for-teaching-or-learning-Get-it-here/ta-p/221088`

Answer (score 1):

Run the below to get your sashelp dataset back:

```
 data sashelp.class ;
 attrib 
 Name                             length= $8
 Sex                              length= $1
 Age                              length= 8
 Height                           length= 8
 Weight                           length= 8
 ;
 infile cards dsd delimiter=',';
 input 
    Name                             :$char.
    Sex                              :$char.
    Age
    Height
    Weight
 ;
 datalines4;
 Alfred,M,14,69,112.5
 Alice,F,13,56.5,84
 Barbara,F,13,65.3,98
 Carol,F,14,62.8,102.5
 Henry,M,14,63.5,102.5
 James,M,12,57.3,83
 Jane,F,12,59.8,84.5
 Janet,F,15,62.5,112.5
 Jeffrey,M,13,62.5,84
 John,M,12,59,99.5
 Joyce,F,11,51.3,50.5
 Judy,F,14,64.3,90
 Louise,F,12,56.3,77
 Mary,F,15,66.5,112
 Philip,M,16,72,150
 Robert,M,12,64.8,128
 Ronald,M,15,67,133
 Thomas,M,11,57.5,85
 William,M,15,66.5,112
 ;;;;
 run;
```

These datalines were generated using `%mp_ds2cards()` - a macro I contributed to the open source MacroCore library, available here:  https://github.com/sasjs/core